# New Qt signals syntax error with overload without this

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots

When I write like

```
 connect(m_someClasspointer, &SomeClassName::SignalA, &CurrentClass::slotMethod);
```

I got error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<void (CurrentClass::*)()>::call(void (CurrentClass::*&)(), QObject*&, void**&)'
             FuncType::template call<Args, R>(static_cast<QStaticSlotObject*>(this_)->function, r, a);
```

while with

```
 connect(m_someClasspointer, &SomeClassName::Signal, this, &CurrentClass::slotMethod);
```

everything is ok. But there is overload in QObject

```
inline QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *asender, const char *asignal,
                                        const char *amember, Qt::ConnectionType atype) const
```

So I absolutely don't understand why first variant didn't work..

Comment: With the new connect syntax that uses a pointer-to-member-function (e.g &CurrentClass::slotMethod) it stops working if the method slotMethod() is overloaded. When overloaded, you get the the compilation error: error: no matching function for call to 'connect'. Same happens if you overload a signal method. So I just refrain from overloading my signal and slot methods. (I should add that you can make it work with overloaded methods: see https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#Overload)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to pass direct function pointers, while the overload you reference takes `const char *`. If you look, you'll find that passing direct function pointers is supported by a template, and there isn't a non-static form of that template.

For overloads that use `const char *`, use the macros SIGNAL and SLOT, e.g. `SIGNAL(SignalA())` and `SLOT(slotMethod())`.